# C lan If statement issue about ds problem

Tags: c

This below is my ds hw code.

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct
{
 int row;
 int col;
 int val;
}term;


void CreateTriplet(term t[],int a[][10],int m, int n)
{
  int i, j, k = 0;
  t[0].row = m;
  t[0].col = n;
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j ++)
    {
      if(a[i][j] == 0)
        continue;
      k++;
      t[k].row = i;
      t[k].col = j;
      t[k].val = a[i][j];
    }
  }
  t[0].val = k;
}

void printTriplet(term t[], int k)

{
  int i;
  for(i = 0 ; i < k ; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\t", t[i].row);
    printf("%d\t", t[i].col);
    printf("%d\n", t[i].val);
  }
}

void findTranspose(term t1[], term t2[])
{
  int i, j, k;
  t2[0].row = t1[0].col;
  t2[0].col = t1[0].row;
  t2[0].val = t1[0].val;
  k = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < t1[0].col; i++)
  {
    for (j = 1; j <=t1[0].val; j++)
    {
      if (t1[j].col == i)
      {
        t2[k].row = t1[j].col;
        t2[k].col = t1[j].row;
        t2[k].val = t1[j].val;
        k++;
      }
    }
  }
}


int main()
{
  int a[10][10], i, j, m, n, zero=0, nonzero;
  term t1[101], t2[102];
  scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
  for(i = 0; i < m ;i++)
  {
    for(j= 0; j < n ;j++)
    {
      scanf("%d]\n", &a[i][j]);
      if(a[i][j]==0)
        zero++;
    }
  }
  if (i*j != i*i && j*j) /* I have no idea how to modify this section for the output*/
  {
    printf("Input matrix has wrong size. Please input again. \n");
  }
  else
  {
    nonzero  =  m * n - zero;
    printf("Sparse matrix by triplet form:\n");
    CreateTriplet(t1, a, m, n);
    printTriplet(t1, nonzero+1);
    findTranspose(t1, t2);
    printf("Transpose of the sparse matrix:\n");
    printTriplet(t2, nonzero+1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The main problem is in the section (if statement.)
When I was writing the if conditional, the input size was 6 * 6. Also, the elements in the matrix are not 6 * 6. My idea is to let the condition determine row * col != input elements. I don't know how to modify the if statement. Can someone help me?

```
**Input**
 
55
15 0 0 22 0
0  0 3 0  0
0  0 0 -6 0 
0  0 0 0  7 
91 0 0 0  0

**Output**

Sparse matrix by triplet form: 
5 5 6
0 0 15
0 3 22
1 2 3
2 3 -6
3 4 7
4 0 91
Transpose of the sparse matrix: 
5 5 6
0 0 15
0 4 91
2 1 3 
3 0 22 
3 2 -6
4 3 7

**Input** 

66
15 0 0 22 0 -15 100 
0 11 3  0 0  0
0  0 0 -6 0  0
0  0 0  0 0  0
91 0 0  0 0  0
0  0 28 0 0  0
1  0 0  0 0  0

**Output**
Input matrix has wrong size. Please input again.
```

Comment: Could you explain specifically and clearly what you want your if statement condition to determin?

Comment: The output of the second task is "Input matrix has wrong size. Please input again."
I know his input size is 6*6 but the element he input does not meet the 6*6 regulations.
So when I want him to input if statement condition, I can successfully pass task1, but the second one 6*6 inputs I want it not run success and prints "Input matrix has wrong size. Please input again."
I don’t know how to rewrite the if statement and make it successful

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
    int val;
} term;

void CreateTriplet (term t[],int a[][10],int m, int n) {
    int i, j, k = 0;
    t[0].row = m;
    t[0].col = n;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j ++) {
            if(a[i][j] == 0)
                continue;
            k++;
            t[k].row = i;
            t[k].col = j;
            t[k].val = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    t[0].val = k;
}

void printTriplet(term t[], int k) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < k ; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", t[i].row);
        printf("%d\t", t[i].col);
        printf("%d\n", t[i].val);
    }
}

void findTranspose(term t1[], term t2[]) {
    int i, j, k;
    t2[0].row = t1[0].col;
    t2[0].col = t1[0].row;
    t2[0].val = t1[0].val;
    k = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < t1[0].col; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <=t1[0].val; j++) {
            if (t1[j].col == i) {
                t2[k].row = t1[j].col;
                t2[k].col = t1[j].row;
                t2[k].val = t1[j].val;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * *argv, char * *envp) {
    int a[10][10], i, j, m, n, zero = 0, nonzero;
    term t1[101], t2[102];
    int ok_or_not = 1;
    while (ok_or_not == 1) {
        scanf ("%d %d", &m, &n);
        if (m * n != m * m) {
            printf ("Input matrix has wrong size. Please input again. \n");
        }
        else {
            ok_or_not = 0;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d]\n", &a[i][j]);
            if (a[i][j] == 0)
                zero++;
        }
    }
    if (i * j != i * i && j * j) { /* I have no idea how to modify this section for the output*/

    } else {
        nonzero = m * n - zero;
        printf("Sparse matrix by triplet form:\n");
        CreateTriplet(t1, a, m, n);
        printTriplet(t1, nonzero + 1);
        findTranspose(t1, t2);
        printf("Transpose of the sparse matrix:\n");
        printTriplet(t2, nonzero + 1);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```